# Run Appium driver on Android device with out launching app(Python)

Tags: python, appium

I am trying to launch appium driver without launching any specific app. Code is as follows:

```
desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
desired_caps['deviceName'] = '############'
desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.android.settings'
desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'com.android.settings.Settings'
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4725/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```

I have tried using:
desired_caps['autoLaunch'] = 'False'
But in that case rest of the script is not executed at all.
Please can anyone give me a solution for it.
(Please don't paste any link as i have searched a lot)

Comment: Im not sure if I understand what you want, but you can just start appium using the command `appium` (if you installed using npm), what the scripts you mention do?

Comment: For example assume that i have two devices connected to one PC and both running at different port. I have made a call from one device, now i need to pick up the call on the other device. So now, what happening is once appium server gets connected to the second (on which call is to be recieved.) "Settings" app is launched. I somehow need to just receive the call, without launching settings package.